# Sublime Text C89 autocompletion

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, c89

I'm using ST3 and code in the C89 standard.
The super useful for-loop auto completion completes to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    /* code */
}
```

But this does not honor the standard. Can this behavior be changed in some config file to complete to:

```
int i = 0;
for (i < count; ++i)
{
    /* code */
}
```

?

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a snippet which is provided by c++ package that ships with sublime (that package covers both C and C++ due to their similarities).

The snippet which is responsible for the auto complete is in **Packages\C++\Snippets\030-for-int-loop-(fori).sublime-snippet**, and looks like this:

```
<snippet>
    <description>For Loop</description>
    <content><![CDATA[for (int ${2:i} = 0; $2 < ${1:count}; ${3:++$2})
{
    ${0:/* code */}
}]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>for</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.c, source.objc, source.c++, source.objc++</scope>
</snippet>
```

You can modify that as you prefer. To do this,

1. Install [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) for sublime. It lets you to look inside sublime packages.
2. Open the **Command pallete** using **ctrl+shift+p**.
3. Enter **prv:o** and select **PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource** from the list.
4. Type C++ and navigate to **Snippets\030-for-int-loop-(fori).sublime-snippet**
5. Modify the code to with this.

   ```
   <snippet>
        <description>For Loop</description>
        <content>
        <![CDATA[int ${2:i} = 0;
   for ( ${2:i} = 0; $2 < ${1:count}; ${3:++$2})
   {
        ${0:/* code */}
   }]]></content>
       <tabTrigger>for</tabTrigger>
       <scope>source.c, source.objc, source.c++, source.objc++</scope>
   </snippet>
   ```
6. And save the file.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Be careful though once you install or update sublime, the changes will be lost. You have to do that again.You could create a new snippet to avoid that using **tools->developer->new snippet**

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to add specific auto- completion in the Sublime Text docs here - 
http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/completions.html. If you already have a Sublime Text package which is performing the C autocomplete for you, you might have to disable it.